# Configure a graphics tablet buttons

Tags: windows, keyboard, mouse, graphics-tablet

I have a "SMART" graphics tablet with two buttons on the tablet itself and two buttons on the pen.
The driver that comes with the tablet only allow me to configure the buttons to be right click or middle click how can I remap these buttons to keyboard keys?

I've tried several applications like X-mouse button, key remmaper, etc and none of these can detect
my buttons input.

Comment: If you think about this carefully then the actual behaviour makes sense. Think about the nature of the driver/application. It has to interact with your device first to be able to acheive this which means it holds priority no matter what other remapping program you run. The key problem then is over-ridding this behaviour (doesn't seem possible at the moment), modifying the driver setting itself manually (more details would help. May possibly take huge effort) or else getting it to run with another driver to potentially over-ride this behaviour (device manager).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used keyremapper to map the right click and middle click to other commands.